On board GPU for specific applications in Windows 11 not working
Windows 11 Graphic Settings for setting applications to use a specific GPU does not seem to be working.
I am trying to set certain applications to run using my on board GPU, but when I set it in Windows Settings, it shows that it is using the right GPU, but when I check Task Manager and check with GPU it is using when running the application(s) it shows my dedicated Nvidia GPU.
This was working in Windows 10, but no longer is working in Windows 11.
Apps I have tested and not working:
Plex
Vivaldi
Battle.net
Discord
Hardware
OS Name Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
Processor   12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900K, 3200 Mhz, 16 Core(s), 24 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Mode   UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
BaseBoard Product   PRIME Z690-A
Drives are all updated
Firmware updated (BIOS upgraded to latest version)

Please add your computer hardware details to the question. Also, have you installed the latest versions of drivers and firmware for all your computer hardware?

OS Name Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
Processor 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900K, 3200 Mhz, 16 Core(s), 24 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Mode UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
BaseBoard Product PRIME Z690-A

Also yes, I have installed drivers/firmware
Latest Bios etc

[Edit] your question instead of submitting comments. Relevant information contained in a comment won’t necessarily prevent a question from being closed.

I have edited the question
